# Peewee SQL - How to use Python any() and all() operators in query

Tags: postgresql, peewee

I would like help in executing a single query joining multiple tables (many-to-many), however I want to incorporate the Peewee PostgreSQL equivalent to Python's any() and all() operators.

**Schema**

- Post: id, post_name
- Tag: id, tag_name
- Author: id, author_name
- Post_Tags: post_id, tag_id
- Post_Authors: post_id, author_id

**Query**

Given a list of multiple tag names and a list of multiple author names, I want all posts that have ANY tag that matches AND have ALL authors that matches:

**Example**

```
tag_list = [“Politics”, “Economy”]
author_list = [“Sarah”, “Alex”]
```

Query would return all posts that have at least one tag that is either “Politics” or “Economy” AND have as its authors “Sarah” and/or “Alex”. However if a post's authors are "Sarah" and "Christina", that post should NOT show up.

This is my current query but it does not satisfy all of my conditions:

```
query = Post
.select()
.join(PostTags)
.join(Tag)
.switch(Post)
.join(PostAuthors)
.join(Authors)
.where((Tag.name << tag_list) & (Author.name << author_list))
```

However I still need to iterate over my query to accomplish what I need:

```
filtered_posts = []

for post in query:
    if all(author.name in author_list for author in post.authors):
        filtered_posts.append(post)
```

Any tips on optimizing my query in Peewee? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use group-by/having to ensure the count of matched authors is equal to the count you are inputting and the count of tags is greater-than or equal to 1. You can also separate the queries and do a UNION or INTERSECT.

The SQL "EXISTS" helper can be useful for the tags portion of your query if you want to use a subquery rather than a JOIN.